# Find the depth of a child from a tree menu with mysqli query

Tags: mysql

```
MYSQL　TABLE

|id|parent_id|
|1 |        0| <- depth 1
|2 |        1| <- depth 2
|3 |        1| <- depth 2
|4 |        2| <- depth 3
|5 |        3| <- depth 3
|6 |        4| <- depth 4
```

I need to find out the depth of id 4 which in the above case it's 3

Is it possible to do it with one mysqli query?
If not, how can I do that with multiple mysqli queries?

Many many thanks.

EDITED

```
function find_depth($id, $depth = 0){
global $con;
$query = "SELECT * from table WHERE `id` = $id";
    if ($result = $con->query($query)){
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
            $row = $result->fetch_array();
            $depth = $depth + 1;
            find_level($row['parent_id'], $depth);
        } else {
            return $depth;
        }
    }
}

find_depth('4')
```

will give me 3

However, I am still looking for a better way to achieve that

Comment: i think, only by procedure in sql or by php code

Comment: Thanks. I am not ready for procedure yet. Too advance for my level. How about by php code? Any good idea?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is not huge, you can do only one query to DB

```
function find_depth($id, $depth = 0) {
  global $con;
  $temp = array();
  $query = "SELECT * from table";
  if ($result = $con->query($query)) {
     while($row = $result->fetch_array()) 
       $temp[$row['id']] = $row['parent_id'];
     do { $depth = $depth + 1; } while($id = $temp[$id]);
  }
  return $depth;       
}

find_depth('4');
```

Comment: Thanks. But when and how do I get the output of $depth from the DO WHILE loop?

Comment: Sorry. forgot to write `return`.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get the correct result. $depth always equal to 2 with whatever id I entered. Note: I have added the missing curly brackets to your first WHILE loop. I know I am getting there :)